# Google App Engine: Failed to Upload Static PNGs

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am trying to upload some pngs as static resources of a Google App Engine application
There is a testImage.png file inside a folder called icons

In the app.yaml file I have specified

```
- url: /icons/*.png
  static_dir: icons
  mime_type: image/png
```

But after the upload, if I try to Get http://.appspot.com/icons/testImage.png

I get a 404

Comment: Post the full content of the handlers: section of your app.yaml, this is most likely an ordering problem.

Comment: @lanGSY Thank you! you are right it depends on the order. I didn't know it

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need the /*.png for the url.  In your static_dir, whatever you put here must match a physical path in your project.  Hence, you must have something like

```
[project-dir]/icons
```

folder that contains your png.

```
   - url: /icons
     static_dir: icons
     mime_type: image/png
```

Comment: I assume you are not using `http://.appspot.com/icons/testImage.png` but `http://<some app id>.appspot.com/icons/testImage.png`.  The answer is the correct way to use static_dir.  Other problems preventing this from working, are the order of things in your app.yaml for instance